# Change values on some criteria in Pandas DataFrame and save it to the new df without affecting the original one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Here's the example. I will write Pandas DataFrame as a list so it's easier to read:

```
df_0 = [1,2,3]
```

I want to change values bigger than 2 to np.nan and save the new DataFrame to new variable df_1. Final result:

```
df_0 = [1,2,3]
df_1 = [1,2,np.nan]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `mask` here

```
df_1=df_0.mask(df_0>2)
df_1
Out[291]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64
df_0
Out[292]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your column name in the dataframe? Let's say, it is `COL`. Then you can do:

```
df_1 = df_0.copy()
df_1.loc[df_1['COL'] >= 2, 'COL'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, there is a keyword `where` that you can make use of.

```
df_0 = pd.Series([1,2,3])
df_1 = df_0.where(df_0 <= 2)

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```